# Defining a header with background color in Latex

Tags: latex, pdflatex

For a small project I'm trying something that feels as if it should be peanut, but *au contraire* (Hey, that's french, never thought I'd remember some parts of that. anyway...).

The thing is, I want a latex layout where the header and footer span the entire pagewidth and have a background color, and also can have some elements on the left, center, or right (like with fancyhdr). The thing is, I simply cannot get this to work without screwing up the rest of the layout.

edit: added example.

Here's an example of what I have tried. The header is shown incorrectly since the background doesn't span the whole width of the page. The footer is not shown at all.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[landscape, top=0cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\definecolor{logoGreen}{RGB}{218,226,87}

\newcommand{\HBG}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[yshift=-2cm] at (current page.north west)
        {
            \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
                \draw[fill=logoGreen] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,2cm);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{\HBG}
\fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[height=1.2cm]{"img/headerimg"}}

\fancyfoot[C]{\includegraphics[height=1.2cm]{"img/footerimg"}}

\fancyhfoffset[]{1in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\headheight 3cm
\footskip -2cm

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\section{first section}
content 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show the structure of the document you have so far (paste the code here) and explain what is being screwed up in the rest of the layout?

Comment: I have added an example of what I have so far

Answer (score 2):

You can use TikZ to position coloured boxes absolutely on the page. See an example [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/fancy-chapter-headings/).

This example includes usage of `\thechapter`, so you can probably go on from there.

Comment: Well, I have actually tried this allready but I couldn't manage to get it working this way whilst keeping the headers available for other content.